# Customizing an applet title in siebel

Tags: siebel

I have a requirement to set the Applet title based on a field value. So what I have done is set the Field property of the Applet Control - AppletTitle. So based on the each record in the applet, it will populate the title based on the field value. But my issue is, at first when loading the applet, it is not showing any value even the first record is selected. It will display, if perform Next Record, Previous Record in the applet etc.

P.S: This applet is based on a VBC.

Can you please support on this issue or suggest any other proper method to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more explanations on why you are trying to change the title name base on the data?

The Applet's Title is rendered while page is loading. So, the title cannot be changed based on the data in case of SIEBEL.

However, you still have a chance to make use of [Applet Toggle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/ConfigApps/ConfigApps_Procedures_UI_layer10.html) and assign a name to each applet which has a search spec based on the field/column you are trying to view.

Answer (score 0):

You may use js transformation. read something about "Open UI" for siebel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).